# Excel Macro to Open EXE

Tags: excel, vba, shell, exe

I am trying to create a macro that will open the file "test.exe" on drive F/. I get "runtime error 5" when running this code below.

```
Sub MacroTangoMike()
' MacroTangoMike Macro
RetVal = Shell("F:/test.exe", 1)
End Sub
```

It works fine though if test.exe is on the C/ drive.

Answer (score 1):

Error 5 is access denied.  Are you sure you have the execute permission on the EXE on the F: drive?

Also you should probably be using backslashes \ in your paths on Windows rather than /.